# List(Of ) default capacity exceeding

Tags: .net, vb.net, list

I have to deserialize a json file that gives me deserialized 130000 nested (`GeneralInfo`)objects

Deserialisation:

```vb
Dim allDATA As List(Of GeneralInfo) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of GeneralInfo))(jstr)
```

Objects:

```vb
Public Class FullData
    Public Property userRunID As ULong
    Public Property data As List(Of String)
End Class

Public Class GeneralInfo
    Public Property id As ULong
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property data As List(Of FullData)
End Class
```

The FullData.data property holds 500 data entries separated by ;. 50 of these entries have max. 50 characters the other 450 contain only one figure.

So I would end up with a 130000 long List(of GeneralInfo). My test with lesser entries was successfull but trying to read all the data stops and gives me an empty object. So my guess is that I have reached the limit of a List(of ) and I would like to have these verified.

Is there a limitation on a List(Of ) and if so, is it possible to extend it so I can use my code?

I am not getting an exception, the object is just empty:

[image]

Comment: limit of the list  - how much RAM have you got...    What is the Exception you are seeing?

Comment: I have updated my question. My RAM is 16 GB

Comment: Is jstr correct?

Comment: The capacity will be increased automatically(with doubling algorithm). So only the memory is the limit. But there is a constructor overload which lets you define the default capacity. Set it to 130000 to avoid unnecessary resize operations.

Comment: Looking at the Shared members of a List object is not useful.  Very hard to guess what a variable named `ads` might have to do with the snippets.  The object is not empty, it does not exist.  Nothing.

Comment: you could try processing the JSON in batches.  Grab batch, convert them to list, then grab another and  use  List.AddRange() to add them to your VB list. until your JSON is processed.  It may help your spot where the error is.  Also try a convert to a JArray.  see if this works

Comment: or if this is in an object {},  try convert whole lot to a JObject

Comment: What does `jstr` look like? (not the whole thing, obviously)